# How do you figure out which thread will run first?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I have this exercise, but I don't understand the reason of the correct answer:

```
 import java.util.Iterator; 
    import java.util.Map.Entry; 
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap; 

    public class Cache {          
    static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();          
    public static void main(String[] args) {         
            chm.put("a", "aaa");         
            chm.put("b", "bbb");         
            chm.put("c", "ccc");                  
            new Thread(){             
                public void run(){                 
                    Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> it = Cache.chm.entrySet().iterator();                 
                    while(it.hasNext()){                     
                        Entry<String, Object> en = it.next();                     
                        if(en.getKey().equals("a") || en.getKey().equals("b")){                         
                            it.remove();                
                        }                 
                    }    
                }         
            }.start();                  

            new Thread(){             
                public void run(){                 
                    Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> it = Cache.chm.entrySet().iterator();                 
                    while(it.hasNext()){                     
                        Entry<String, Object> en = it.next();                     
                        System.out.print(en.getKey()+", ");                 
                    }             
                }         
            }.start();             
    } 
}
```

There were 4 possible answers:

1. It may print any combination of the keys.
2. It may print any combination except: c,
3. It may print any combination except: a, or b, or a, b, or b, a
4. It may print any combination except: b, c,

The correct answer for this exercise is 3.

Why this is the correct answer?

I thought this exercise may print any combination of the keys, because there are two thread in this main, so I don't know which of the both will start for first. If the second thread will start for first, I will have all the keys in the ConcurrentHashMap, so it will print a and b.
So, my answer for this exercise was 1. But the exercise considers it as wrong answer. Why?

How do I figure out which thread will start for first?

Thanks a lot!

A.

Comment: format your code

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to know which thread will run first, although I assume the first one created will.  However, they will both run concurrently anyway, so theoretically any combination of entries may be printed, from all or just the "c".  Using join() will guarantee the thread start order.

Comment: you can use the JProfiler or jvisualvm (../JDK1.8.0_66/bin)

Comment: Also, there's a good chance you'll get a "ConcurrentModifcationException".

Comment: Why does exercise indicate as correct answer the 3? In my opinion, correct answer is 1.

Comment: @Adryr83 You are confusing people because you ask 2 questions : "How to know which thread starts first" and "Why C is the correct answer". You may edit your post to limit it to only one (and if you need, create a new post for your second question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to determine in advance which thread will start first beside you create one first.

It only depends on the `Scheduler` which is part of the `JVM`. It does `Thread`s management.

If you want to wait to the first thread and then start the second you can easily use `firstThread.join()` and then start the second thread.

Comment: So, the correct answer of this exercise is wrong or it is very rough, isn't it?

Comment: @Adryr83 Yes, the (3) is correct answer. 
So, as it seems the first Thread only removes following keys: "a" and "b", and the second thread only reads all the remaining keys and prints them. There will not be a moment when Printer Thread would not print key "c". Also there won't be a moment when only "a" or "b" or ("a" and "b") or ("b" and "a") will be printed. Because it's guaranteed the "c" will be printed soon or later.

Comment: but if you don't know which tread will start for first, it is possible to print all combination of the keys (even a, or b, or a, b, or b, a). So, the answer 1 should be corrected and not the answer 3. If second thread will start for first, it will print all the keys.

Comment: @Adryr83 Actually you don't need to know which thread will start executing first in this case. The second thread prints all the remaining elements. It's guaranteed that this second thread guaranteed print at least "c", because the first thread doesn't remove key "c" from the container. The first thread only removes "a" and "b" keys so the (3) answer provides correct one.

Answer (score 1):

We can not determine which thread is run first .It's totally depend upon  the Scheduler which is part of the JVM.

if you want to execute both thread run in sequence manner(one after another) then use wait and notify to implement this(like producer consumer problem).